# What to do about a false positive in clamtk

Tags: security, malware, antivirus, clamav, clamtk

I am getting a message from clamtk antivirus after running a scan on the download folder the result said 10 viruses found how can 10 viruses  be found if nothing in the download folder but some files that I personally know is safe?

Comment: show us the output.  are the files hidden?

Comment: No it visible in the folder

Answer (score 1):

clamtk is a gui front end for clamav & allows for some customization: under Preferences, go to "whitelist", and simply add the files there you want clamav to ignore. Alternatively, for well-known applications & system files (vs your own files), you can report them to clamav as false-positives: http://www.clamav.net/contact